# Equilibrium position of a body attached to spring of spring constant $=k$

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy, free-body-diagram, spring, equilibrium

I am really confused by the equilibrium position of a body attached to a spring, when do we use conservation of energy i.e mgx=(1/2)kx^2 and when to use mg=kx?

Here X in all cases is the distance from initial position to the position where it comes to rest

[image]

Comment: Equilibrium means that the forces acting on your weight add up to zero. There is the gravitational force pulling downwards and the spring force that works against it when you pull the spring apart. The extension of the spring where the spring force cancels out the gravitational force is your equilibrium position in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not conservation of energy, it's the minimization of energy. The potential energy with gravity "on" is:

$$U(x)=\frac 1 2 kx^2+mgx $$

which is minimized via:

$$\frac{dU}{dx} = kx + mg =0$$

or

$$ x=-\frac{mg} k$$

Thus, the energy stored in the spring is:

$$ E_0=\frac 1 2 kx^2=\frac 1 2 \frac{(mg)^2}k$$

while the gravitational potential energy is:

$$ V_0 = -mgx = -\frac{(mg)^2} k = -2E_0 $$

If you define a new coordinate:

$$ y = x-\frac{mg} k$$

then:

$$ U(y) = \frac 1 2 k(y-\frac{mg} k)^2+mg(y-\frac{mg} k)$$

$$ U(y)=\frac 1 2 k[y^2-2y\frac{mg} k+\frac{(mg)^2} {k^2})] + mgy-\frac{(mg)^2} k$$

$$U(y)=\frac 1 2 ky^2 -\frac 1 2 \frac{(mg)^2} k$$

Thus you have a S.H.O with the ground state energy offset equal to the negative of the energy stored in the spring:

$$ E_0+V_0=-\frac 1 2\frac{(mg)^2} k = -E_0 $$